# Is there any way to make div fly in/out with pure CSS

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to use CSS animations to make a div fly in/out of the page upon a button click. I know how to animate with CSS, but my problem: if I try to make a div's position like -1000%, there will be a horizontal scroll bar. I don't want that to show up, but I don't want to disable the scrollbar either.

Comment: Not that simple. Please give us some example html structure. AND what should trigger the"fly out"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the ***position*** of the element in CSS, you can use `animation` and `@keyframes` rule. Set your element to **relative** or **absolute** according to how you want to control the positioning of the element within the parent, and use the `left` or `top` position in your css animation rule. @ `0%` set the **left** position off the page and bring it in at `100%` => 0

```css
body {
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

#header {
  position: absolute; 
  left: 37%;
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 3rem;
  animation: slideup 1.2s ease-in-out;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  animation: slidein 1s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    top: -1900px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <img id='image' src="https://assets3.thrillist.com/v1/image/1679696/size/tmg-facebook_social.jpg">
  <h2 id="header">My Vacation</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, it has a scrollbar that stretches all the way to the right and left... I don't want the scrollbar... (I have a fullscreen no-scroll background image).

Comment: @ublec you can add `overflow: hidden;` to your body and it will remove the scroll issue.

Comment: Yes, I did that. But what if I want my website to have scroll?

Comment: My suggestion would be to use a side slidein and use `overflow-x:hidden; ` this way you can still have use of the y scroll

Answer (score 3):

Use keyframes. For example:

```css
.fly {
    animation: superman-fly-right ease-in-out 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes superman-fly-right {
    from {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateX(100vw);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it via `translate3d`

```css
@keyframes fadeInUp {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0,140px,0);
  }

  to {
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    opacity: 1    
  }
}

.animated {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.animatedFadeInUp {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fadeInUp {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fadeInUp;
}
```

```html
<div class="animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp">
  <h2>This text will fly in from bottom and slowly appear</h2>
</div>
```